# How to add a custom 404 page in Vite with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm building a multi page web application using Vite 4.2.1 and vanilla JavaScript. I would like to add a custom 404 page to my application.

I've tried searching for a solution online, but most of the solutions I've found are either for a specific JavaScript framework or use a different build tool.

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Without a client router Vite does not have a concept of `custom 404 page` - every page is `custom` from Vite's point of view. Also, if you're not using any JS framework - there is very little use of Vite, you can simply go vanilla all the way. Since your application is multipage - simply make one of the pages to look like a 404 page and configure your server to serve this page in case of 404 errors.